# Model is null on button click ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I loaded a partial view using ajax into a view. The partial view has a dropdownlist in it, but Whenever I select a dropdown option and click a button in the partial view to connect, I get an error that the Model is null. This is weird because the Model has already populated  forthe dropdown and it does not go to any actions on my controller on a breakpoint. I have spent several days on this.

The Error is:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   App_Web_m2cylvfu.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ServerName)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ServerName, Model.ServerNames, "-- Select Server --")
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="btnConnect" type="submit" name="Connect" value="Connect" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btnConnect').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();

    var selectedServerName = $('#ServerName').val()
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("ConnectToServer", "Settings")',
      data: {
        'servername': selectedServerName
      },
      cache: false,
      type: 'post',
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
        var $el = $("#DatabaseName");
        $el.empty(); // remove old options
        $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", '').text('Please Select'));
        $.each(result, function(value, key) {
          $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));
        });
      }
    });

  });

}
```

**Controller**

```
public PartialViewResult Index() {
    var afConnectionModel = new AFConnectionModel() {
        ServerNames = GetServers()
    };
    return PartialView(afConnectionModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ConnectToServer(string servername) {
    return Json(new {
        foo = "bar", baz = "Blech"
    });
}

private static dynamic GetServers() {
    var piSystems = new PISystems().Select(c => new Afart {
        Id = c.Name, ServerName = c.Name
    });
    return new SelectList(piSystems, "Id", "ServerName");
} 

public class Afart
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string ServerName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code to pinpoint the where and the why

Comment: Its throwing the exception in the razor code: Model.ServerNames. If I knew why, I wouldn't be asking the question. :-)

Comment: Are you using a LINQ query to project PISystems() into.... Afart?

Comment: well what does ServerNames look like..

Comment: I have added the class for the ServerNames. Yes, I'm using LINQ to project into Afart. I should mention that the dropdown is populated correctly, and I can make a selection from the dropdown. Only when I click the "Connect" do I get the error.

Comment: It seems like the submit button is not calling my ajax submit but is trying to connect to the form submit itself.

Comment: Is that JS code to hookup the click event running in the partial view or the host view?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The javascript was not being called in the partial view and it was going directly to a controller action and returning without reloading the viewbag data.

Answer (score 0):

> it was not hitting controller because you were having some mistakes in
>   Javascript code... please try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnConnect').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();

    var selectedServerName = $('#ServerName').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("ConnectToServer", "Settings")',
      data: {
        servername: selectedServerName
      },
      cache: false,
      type: 'post',
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
        var el = $("#DatabaseName");
        el.empty(); // remove old options
        el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", '').text('Please Select'));
        $.each(result, function(value, key) {
          $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));
        });
      }
    });

  });
}
```